Make Cloud Run service and android App connect to the same Firestore db
I created a Service with Cloud Run. Using the Integrations tab of the Service, I can connect to a Firestore db instance. Unfortunately, I can't choose an existing instance, hence I have to create a new one.
How can I make the Service and the Android App share the same Firestore db? I am not able to choose the db used by the Android App, either, as apparently there is no way in Google Cloud Console, or in Firebase console, or in firebase-firestore library for Android.
To add more details, this is the way suggested by Firestore tutorials to get access to the database. There is no way to choose which one:
private var fireStoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


Why don't you set the DB to use in your code running in Cloud Run directly instead of using the integration?

Also you can change the db in android, why you mention that apparently not? please add more details on how your setting these in your code

@Puteri I have tried but couldn't find a way to specify which database to connect. See the edited question

When you're using the following line of code:
private var fireStoreDB = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

You're creating a new instance of the default Firebase Firestore database.

To add more details, this is the way suggested by Firestore tutorials to get access to the database. There is no way to choose which one.

Yes, there is. If you want to create a new instance of another Firebase Firestore database, then you have to pass the ID of the database to the getInstance() method:
val app = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(app, "test")

For more info please also check:

Manage multiple Firestore databases in a project
The announcement video
Official documentation regarding managing databases


Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
